# Algorithm to find a vector parallel to a plane and perpendicular to another vector

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I'm trying to derive a formula to extract vector `u`.

[image: vector-plane-vector setup image]

I'm given some initial data:

1. Plane `F` with the method to extract its normal `n = F->normal()`.
2. vector `c` that does not lie within the plane `F` and passes through some point `E` that also does not lie within the plane `F`.

And some constrains to use:

1. The desired vector `u` is perpendicular to the vector `c`.
2. Vector `u` is also perpendicular to some vector `r` which is not given. The vector `r` is parallel to the plane `F` and also perpendicular to the vector `c`. Therefore, we can say the vectors `c`, `r` and `u` are **orthogonal**.

Let's denote `*` as dot product, and `^` operator is cross product between two 3d vectors.

The calculation of the vector `u` is easy by using cross product: `vec3 u = c^r`. So, my whole task is narrowed down to **how to find the vector `r` which is parallel to a given plane `F` and at the same time perpendicular to the given vector `c`**.

Because we know that `r` is parallel to `F`, we can use plane's normal and dot product: `n*r = 0`. Since `r` is unknown, an infinite number of lines can satisfy the aforementioned equation. So, we can also use the condition that `r` is perpendicular to `c`: `r*c = 0`.

**To summarize**, there are two dot-product equations that should help us to find the vector `r`:

```
r*c = 0;
r*n = 0;
```

However, I am having hard time trying to figure out how to obtain the vector `r` coordinates provided the two equations, in algorithmic way. Assuming `r = (x, y, z)` and we want to find `x`, `y` and `z`; it does not seem possible from only two equations:

```
x*c.x + y*c.y + z*c.z = 0;
x*n.x + y*n.y + z*n.z = 0;
```

I feel like I'm missing something, e.g., I need a third constrain. Is there anything else needed to extract `x`, `y` and `z`? Or do I have a flaw in my logic?

Comment: using your notation: `r = c ^ n`

Comment: As r is parallel to F, it is orthogonal to n. Hence you are looking for a vector perpendicular to both n and c, which is found with the cross-product n ^ c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the vector r by computing the cross product of n and c.

This will be automatically satisfy r.c=r.n=0

You are right that your two equations will have multiple solutions.  The other solutions are given by any scalar multiple of r.